# Show wordpress categories as hierarchical

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, categories

I am trying to print out the categories associated to a post using the code below. By default it seems to order it alphabetically. Is there a way that I can order it by category hierarchy?

```
<footer class="categories-links">
<?php $post_category = get_the_category($post->ID); if ( $post_category==true 
) { ?>  
<span > <?php the_category(' ') ?></span> <?php }?>
</footer>
```

Currently I have for example:
Parent category: Fruits, 
Sub category: Trees, 
Sub sub category: apples,

And it prints out as apples - fruits - trees. 
Whereas it needs to be Fruits - trees - apples

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. This is from [Stackexchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/41548/get-categories-hierarchical-order-like-wp-list-categories-with-name-slug-li/41559). But this is pefect way to get
You can also pass `$args` in categories. For more [info](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_categories/)

```
  hierarchical_category_tree( 0 ); // the function call; 0 for all categories; or cat ID  

function hierarchical_category_tree( $cat ) {
    // wpse-41548 // alchymyth // a hierarchical list of all categories //

  $next = get_categories('hide_empty=false&orderby=name&order=ASC&parent=' . $cat);

  if( $next ) :    
    foreach( $next as $cat ) :
    echo '<ul><li><strong>' . $cat->name . '</strong>';
    echo ' / <a href="' . get_category_link( $cat->term_id ) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $cat->name ) . '" ' . '>View ( '. $cat->count . ' posts )</a>  '; 
    echo ' / <a href="'. get_admin_url().'edit-tags.php?action=edit&taxonomy=category&tag_ID='.$cat->term_id.'&post_type=post" title="Edit Category">Edit</a>'; 
    hierarchical_category_tree( $cat->term_id );
    endforeach;    
  endif;

  echo '</li></ul>'; echo "\n";
}
```

Comment: I did try that, however, i get the following error.  Cannot redeclare hierarchical_category_tree() (previously declared.

Comment: Just change the function name

Comment: @Pilgrimiv. Any other issues ?

Comment: Hmm. still getting the same error.  Is it literally copy and paste  (inside php tags) tried changing function hierarchical_category_tree, to function hierarchical_category_trees (3rd line of code above)

Comment: @Pilgrimiv also 1st line

Comment: Error is: Fatal error: Cannot redeclare hierarchical_category_tree() (previously declared in templates\content-cat.php:29) in \templates\content-cat.php on line 43

Comment: and when i changed the function name, :  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function hierarchical_category_treess() in \templates\content-cat.php:27

Comment: Write that function in `functions.php` file